# Java : No output or result show

Tags: java, output

My program is supposed to show the calculation of the worker's total salary but somehow after all the input in include the program is end without showing any result.

It also to check if the total hours enter is over 40 and if does, it will calculate the overtime salary.

```
 public class GajiTest {
 public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of Employees: ");
    int numberOfEmp= input.nextInt();

    int[] arrayList= new int[numberOfEmp];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){

    System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");
    String empName= input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: ");
    int rate= input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");  
    int hours=input.nextInt();

    class Salary {

    public double CalculateGaji(int hours,int rate){

   if (hours >=40)
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay = (hours-40) *(rate*1.5);
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+"\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

    else
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay =0;
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+ "\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

  }
  }
  }}}
```

Comment: I cant see main here

Comment: Where you use Salay.CalculateGaji(hours,rate) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem add two lines try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of Employees: ");
    int numberOfEmp= input.nextInt();

    int[] arrayList= new int[numberOfEmp];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){

    System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");
    String empName= input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: ");
    int rate= input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");  
    int hours=input.nextInt();

    Salary sal=new Salary();
    sal.CalculateGaji(hours,rate,empName);




    }
    }
    }



class Salary {

    public void CalculateGaji(int hours,int rate,String empName){

   if (hours >=40)
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay = (hours-40) *(rate*1.5);
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+"\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

    else
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay =0;
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+ "\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it is not printing anything is because you are not calling your method `CalculateGaji()` of `class Salary`.

You need to call it by creating the object of the class `Salary`. (After the local class in the main method.)

```
Salary salary = new Salary();
salary.CalculateGaji(hours,rate);
```

Apart from it, there are a few things I would like to say,

1. You are creating an array of integers `int[] arrayList= new int[numberOfEmp];` ArrayList is something else. [What is an ArrayList?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) There should be no need to write the name of the variable to be `arrayList`. It might confuse you at some stage.
2. As per your code, you have created the class `class Salary` in your `main method`. This way it becomes the `[Local Class][2]`. If it is what you want then, it is find. Otherwise you could have written your `class Salary` out side main method and outside class `class GajiTest`.

But I don't see any need of creating any local class to achieve it. You can directly do it the following way,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of Employees: ");
    int numberOfEmp= input.nextInt();

    int[] arrayList= new int[numberOfEmp];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++){

    System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");
    String empName= input.next();

    System.out.print("Enter hourly rate: ");
    int rate= input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");  
    int hours=input.nextInt();


   if (hours >=40)
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay = (hours-40) *(rate*1.5);
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+"\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

    else
   {
   double regPay=  hours * rate;
   double otPay =0;
   double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
   System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName+ "\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
  }

  }
```

Comment: the result is still the same, error: cannot find symbol
  salary.CalculateGaji(hours, rate);    all the calculations still cant be retrieved. I created it this way because i need at least 2 method

Comment: In that case you can just create a simple method to calculate rather than messing up with local classes.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I think what you are trying to do is create an array of employees and print out their names and salaries. There are multiple errors in your code that will not allow it to function if that is your intention.

Here is the code to create an array of employees and print out their names and salaries based on your CalculateGaji function:

```
public class calculateSalary {

static class employee{
    private double rate;
    private double hours;
    private String empName;

    public employee(){}

    public void setRate(double value){
        rate = value;
    }

    public void setHours(double value){
        hours = value;
    }

    public void setName(String value){
        empName = value;
    }

    public void CalculateGaji(){

           if (hours >=40){
               double regPay=  hours * rate;
               double otPay = (hours-40) *(rate*1.5);
               double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
               System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName +"\n Regular pay: " +   regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
          }

            else{
                double regPay=  hours * rate;
                double otPay =0;
                double totalPay= regPay + otPay;
                System.out.print("\nEmployee name: " + empName + "\n Regular pay: " + regPay +"\n Overtime pay: " + otPay+ "\n Total pay: " + totalPay+ "\n"+ "\n");
          }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of Employees: ");
        int numberOfEmp= input.nextInt();

        employee[] employeeArray= new employee[numberOfEmp];

        for (int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++){

            employeeArray[i] = new employee();
            System.out.println("Enter Employee Name: ");
            employeeArray[i].setName(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter hourly rate: ");
            employeeArray[i].setRate(input.nextDouble());

            System.out.println("Enter hours worked: ");  
            employeeArray[i].setHours(input.nextDouble());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < employeeArray.length; i++){
            employeeArray[i].CalculateGaji();
        }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.